# Typo resistant NavigationViewItem.Tag in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I am trying pass type argument to Tag attribute of NavigationViewItem element in XAML:

```xml
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:page="using:MyApp.Pages"
>
    <NavigationView>
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Test page" Tag="{x:Type page:TestPage}" Icon="Library" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" />
    </NavigationView>
</Page>
```

With error: "The Type x:Type was not found.".

When I create custom extension for this:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using System;

namespace MyApp.Xaml
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(ReturnType = typeof(Type))]
    public sealed class TypeExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public Type Type { get; set; }

        public TypeExtension(Type type)
        {
            Type = type;
        }

        protected override object ProvideValue() => Type;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```xml
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:t="using:MyApp.Xaml"
    xmlns:page="using:MyApp.Pages"
>

    <NavigationView >
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Test page" Tag="{t:Type page:TestPage}" Icon="Library" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame" />
    </NavigationView>
</Page>
```

It is still not working with error:

```
Error   WMC0100 XAML TypeExtension type cannot be constructed. In order to be constructed in XAML, a type cannot be abstract, interface, nested, generic or a struct, and must have a public default constructor.
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve passing Type to Tag attribute or another solution to prevent typos in class names?

For completness my selection change handler:

```cs
        private void MainNavigationView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.SelectedItem is NavigationViewItem item && item.Tag is Type pageType)
            {
                contentFrame.Navigate(pageType);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the `Type` like this:

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(ReturnType = typeof(Type))]
public sealed class TypeExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type? Type { get; set; }

    protected override Type? ProvideValue()
    {
        return Type;
    }
}
```

```xml
<NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Tag="{l:Type Type=pages:HomePage}"/>
```

But there's an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7017) in WinUI 3 when you return `Type` with `MarkupExtensions`, so you'll have to wait until they fix it.